# bracket is lost in PHP code

Tags: php, if-statement

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Plz, I wonder Can you help me, I can't find it.

```
if( isPost() ) {
    extract($_POST);
    if( validation_required([$name , $family ,$username , $email , $password]) ) {
        $conn = connectToDB();
        if (!userGet($username,$conn){
             saveUsers($_POST) ? redirect("index.php") : $status = 'you are failed';
        } else {
            $status = "This username is exist";
        }
    } else {
        $status = 'your information is not valid';
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot a closing ')' in `if (!userGet($username,$conn){`

Comment: `extract($_POST)` - are you sure you want to use that?

Comment: See the if statement with $conn in it. You haven't closed it. Close it with ')'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's line 5:

```
if (!userGet($username,$conn){
```

Should have 2 closing brackets

```
if (!userGet($username,$conn)){
```